# AWS JIRA CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jira, aws-cloudformation, confluence

I am trying to deploy JIRA on AWS, but am having a hard time setting it up. I couldn't find any document on how to troubleshoot the following errors.

First one is:

> S3 error: Access Denied For more information check

I made a S3 bucket public, and was able to bypass this error, but I don't want it to be public, but since creating a whole new stack, I don't have any information of an instance to adjust allow permission to S3 bucket.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this error without adjusting the bucket to be public?

After bypassing the previous error, I was getting this error:

> S3 error: The specified key does not exist.

I definitely couldn't find how to troubleshoot this issue? What needs to be done to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Access Denied` indicates that you do not have permissions to access content in Amazon S3. The normal way of providing these permissions is:

- Create an **IAM Role**
- Assign permission to the role sufficient to access the S3 bucket
- Assign the Role to the Amazon EC2 instance running the software

The `specified key does not exist` error basically means *File Not Found*.

If you wish any further trouble shooting tips, you'll need to provide details of what you are doing (eg the commands used) and what specific errors you are receiving.

You may also wish to read:

- [Getting started with JIRA Data Center on AWS - Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/getting-started-with-jira-data-center-on-aws-861253115.html)
- [JIRA on AWS - Quick Start](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/jira/)